# Timetable - database design

Tags: mysql

I want to create a typical school timetable for each user.

**The end product should look like this:**

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|  h | Monday  | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|  1 | SCIENCE | MATHS   | ENGLISH   | FRENCH   | ART    |
|  2 | SCIENCE | MATHS   | ENGLISH   | FRENCH   | ART    |
|  3 |         | MUSIC   | HISTORY   | GEO      |        |
|  4 |         | MUSIC   | HISTORY   | GEO      |        |
|  5 | HEALTH  | PE      | MATHS     |          |        |
|  6 | HEALTH  | PE      | MATHS     |          |        |
|  7 |         |         |           |          |        |
|  8 |         |         |           | SCIENCE  |        |
|  9 |         |         |           | SCIENCE  |        |
| 10 |         |         | PE        |          |        |
| 11 |         |         | PE        |          |        |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Now I want to create a MySQL table for this application.

**My idea was this (but is this the best way because this table would have many many columns):**

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+----
| user_id | mo1 | mo2 | mo3 | mo4 | mo5 | mo6 | mo7 | mo8 | mo9 | mo10 | mo11 | tu1 | tu2 | tu3 | tu4 | tu5 | tu6 | tu7 | tu8 | tu9 | tu10 | tu11 | we1 | we2 | ...
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+----
|    ?    |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  | ...
|    ?    |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |   ?  |   ?  |  ?  |  ?  | ...
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+----
```

In conclusion: What would be the best design of a MySQL table for a typical school timetable (with user_id)?

The user can input a text/subject-name for each lesson via many HTML text-fields (maybe there is also a better solution). But one important thing I forgot to say is that I have no courses-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a table for each "Entity" (Users, Days, Subjects, Hours) to avoid duplication and then probably a pivot table called "Schedule".

```
User (id, username) 
Days (id, day_of_the_week)
Subjects (id, title)
Hours (id)
Schedule (id, id_user, id_subject, id_hour, id_day)
```

Comment: So that the `schedule`-table looks like the table I sticked to my first post? Because then I would have many rows instead of many columns

Comment: use only the "id" of the entities in the pivot table! You are wrongly using the "day_of_the_week" and "title" for "day" and "subject" columns

Comment: You need to first write down in "plain english" what you want to do.
i.e. "Select the SCHEDULE where the USER is Klipp AND the HOUR is n AND DAY is m"

Comment: Would it hit the performance hardly if the subject-column in the schedule-table is a string (8 letters)? Because I thought about that the user can input there his subject and room in one string

Comment: you need to create a table for the "subjects". When user inputs his schedule you need to chain a few queries. For example you need  checking if the subject he picked  already exists in the DB. If it doesn't exist you create it otherwise you use the "id" of the existing one. Very important you avoid duplication

Comment: Wouldn't this be okay? : `1 (id) | 3 (id_users) | 2 (id_day) | 1 (id_hour) | "SCIENCE 101 (string from the user)` Or would it be better if I create a new table for rooms?

Comment: Since many users could add same class you are encouraged to create a specific table for the Subject. This is the good practice. you can obvioulsy do the other way and you wouldn't see downside until your project goes large scale or you required more flexibility in the queries

Comment: So would you insert a string like "SCIENCE 101" into the subjects-table or would you create a column for the subjects and a column for the rooms?

Comment: "insert a string like "SCIENCE 101" into the subjects-table"

Comment: And this won't hit the performance if there are many of these strings?

Comment: No you will only have one and only one "SCIENCE 101" in your DB. how do you see this unperformant?

Comment: I agree, don't know how I got on this thought :)